# CORS issue in (Vercel Hosting) MERN Stack Project preflight request doesn't pass access control

Tags: node.js, cors, mern, preflight, cross-origin-read-blocking

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hr-360.vercel.app/users/login' from origin'https://hr360.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

POST https://hr-360.vercel.app/users/login net::ERR_FAILED

I add following codes but error still there:

```
npm install cors

const cors = require('cors');

// First attempt
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["https://hr360.vercel.app"],
    methods: ["POST", "GET"],
    credentials: true
}));

// Second attempt
// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // '*' allows any origin, you can restrict it to specific origins
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Configure CORS in at most one place. Here, you're configuring it twice. Either rely on Express's CORS middleware library (preferable) or manually set CORS response headers (questionable), but don't do both.

Comment: If the problem persists, edit your question and add the relevant client code.

Comment: Besides, are you sure the issue doesn't simply stem from a typo? Did you mean to send a request to `https://hr360.vercel.app` (no hyphen) rather than to `https://hr-360.vercel.app`? In that case, you wouldn't even need CORS, since the request would be same-origin.

Comment: i don't do both. i mentioned it above that these two codes were two separate attempts to resolve cors issue and the web address with hyphen is the server domain while no hyphen one is the frontend domain

Comment: Fair enough. Then add the relevant client code to your question.